# some thing wrong with hp printer

Tags: printing, hp

I'm using ubuntu16.04

output of `hp-check -rt`:

```
Saving output in log file: /home/hqiu/Downloads/hplip-3.16.10/hp-check.log

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro    
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball   
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                      
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode    
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).   

Check types:                                                                    
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                          
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)    
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                       
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                    
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version


---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Host: hqiu
 Proc: 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 16.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.16.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  16.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.16.3

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=yes
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=yes
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.16.3
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.16.3



Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1213nf_MFP?zc=NPI418CCD

[installation]
date_time = 11/25/16 11:37:17
version = 3.16.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

--------------------------
|  External Dependencies |
--------------------------

 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.10.6          OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.17.1          OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.25          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.6.32          OK         -
 error: xsane         xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             -               MISSING    'xsane needs to be installed'
 error: cups          CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             -               INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.18            OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -

-------------------------
|  General Dependencies |
-------------------------

 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.23'         OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 error: libusb        libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             MISSING    'libusb needs to be installed'
 python3-pyqt4-dbus   PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 python3-pyqt4        PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.2           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.5.1           OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 error: libnetsnmp-devel libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           -               MISSING    'libnetsnmp-devel needs to be installed'
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.1.0           OK         -
 error: sane-devel    SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'sane-devel needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.0           OK         -
 error: cups-image    CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-image needs to be installed'
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.5.1           OK         -
 error: cups-devel    CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-devel needs to be installed'
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.3.0           OK         -

---------------
|  COMPILEDEP |
---------------

 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               4.9.3           OK         -
 error: libtool       libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'libtool needs to be installed'
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -

----------------------
|  Python Extentions |
----------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -

-----------------------
|  Scan Configuration |
-----------------------

 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -
'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

-----------------------
|  Other Dependencies |
-----------------------


------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

No Scanner found.

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


Laserjet
--------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: implicitclass:Laserjet

Lexmark-International-Lexmark-X463deCMD:PS,URF,JPEG
---------------------------------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: dnssd://Lexmark%20X463de._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=9dbe3a4a-90e7-4013-8671-daa463cf9418
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Lexmark-International-Lexmark-X463deCMD:PS,URF,JPEG.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/Lexmark-International-Lexmark-X463deCMD:PS,URF,JPEG.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: /usr/bin/lpstat: Unknown destination "Lexmark-International-Lexmark-X463deCMD:PS".
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------


-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-client' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool-bin' package is missing/incompatible 

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible 

Total Errors: 8
Total Warnings: 1


Done.
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting STOPPED status for the jobs you give for printing? And not printing at all?

Comment: @Logan It's always HELD status and not printing...

Comment: I have the same issue using hplip-3.20.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I get the following errors:warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148dw_FC12CE_@NPIFC12CE.local.ppd ppd file
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.    hp-setup -1 no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently migrated to ubuntu a month ago. I have a network printer and the model is *HP LaserJet Pro MFP m126nw*. I got a STOPPED status for all the jobs I submitted. I executed a command line utiliy `sudo hp-setup -i` and directing the program to 'd' download a new plugin from HP. This solved my problem.

Using the utiliy is quite simple. It prompts to first select the connection type. Just proceed with the steps. In the end, just verify your ".ppd" file by selecting `y`. I guess it is the fourth step from the end. And the last three steps ask for description and some optional stuff where it just gives a single option to quit. Just press **Enter**. Submit a Test page for printing.

I hope this helps you too.

Comment: doesn't work for me...